# HTML Sidebar is not rendering for some of our users

Tags: google-apps-script

We have an HTML sidebar that we render for the users to log in, and starting last Friday we started getting reports that it is not rendering for some users. The message they all get in the console is:

'dropping postMessage ...mae_html_user.js:36 was from unexpected window'

This only happens in Chrome. Works in Incognito mode or any other browser. Has someone run into this before?

Comment: There is reportedly an issue with the current(?) version of the chrome browser.  IT has also been suggested the issue is related to the LastPass extension for Chrome. The issue gets resolved if the extension is disabled.   Could you post the code where you define the HtmlService.createHtml...  and SpreadsheetApp.getUI()...  ?  Also, see the [posted bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6655) and star it for updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a report of the Lastpass extension blocking add-ons. Its possible this extension is blocking, or possibly there was a change to the Chrome API that breaks add-ons.

> https://plus.google.com/u/0/110895331952973956190/posts/cSMLnDk6gKx

Comment: Thanks! that looks like a possibility! Although we were able to fix this by moving it to a modeless dialog box and stripping all javascript from the page.